# Change a Select Option value with no id/class

Tags: javascript, jquery

There's this website that I want to change how they display their dropdown menu.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wu718.jpg

I wanted to make it so that the default value is "Items for Sale", instead of "Forum Topics"

Here's their source code.

```
       <select name="sec" style="margin-top:5px;width:138px;">

            <option value="topics">Forum Topics</option>

            <option value="s">Items for Sale</option>

            <option value="b">Want to Buys</option>

            <option value="users">Members</option>

       </select>
```

Since I don't really care about how it looks, I just want to change the value="topics" to value="s" even without changing the texts.

I've read some tutorials, but they mostly use IDs and Classes as a selector, in this case, how do I target this Select from many other in their website and change the value.

Comment: The part that confuses me is when you say you want to change "their" website. Do you have control of their HTML?

Comment: @j08691 

I often visit this website, I will be using something like tampermonkey to save the changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```js
$('select[name=sec]').val('s');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="sec" style="margin-top:5px;width:138px;">
    <option value="topics">Forum Topics</option>
    <option value="s">Items for Sale</option>
    <option value="b">Want to Buys</option>
    <option value="users">Members</option>
</select>
```

I *think* this is what you're describing in the comments below:

```js
var dropdown = $('select[name=sec]');
// change the  s  option to  items
dropdown.find('option[value=s]').attr('value', 'items');
// change the  topics  option to  s
dropdown.find('option[value=topics]').attr('value', 's');
// change the dropdown's value to s  
// (first option should continue to be selected because its value is now s)
dropdown.val('s');

// (this is for demo purposes only)
dropdown.after($("<div>").text("New HTML is: " + dropdown[0].outerHTML));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="sec" style="margin-top:5px;width:138px;">
    <option value="topics">Forum Topics</option>
    <option value="s">Items for Sale</option>
    <option value="b">Want to Buys</option>
    <option value="users">Members</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you! 

I just want to make sure I understood it. This line is going to a option that have the name "sec" and have the option value of "s", how do I then change the value of the "s"?

Comment: @MichaelKenji The selector `select[name=sec]` selects a `<select>` element that has a `name` attribute with the value `"sec"`. I didn't understand the second part of your question. You want to change the value of what "s"?

Comment: I want to change the first option value ("topics") to ("s")

Answer (score 0):

You can use the name or any other attribute.

for css

```
select[name="sec"]
```

or jquery

```
$('select[name="sec"]').
```

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/u8544ko4/2/) inspect element from your browser to see the changes
 you can select  a select dropdown list  with `select[name=sec]` and select the first option  with  `option:first`

```
 $('select[name=sec] option:first').val('s');
```

and if you need to change any of options just use `.eq()`

```
$('select[name=sec] option').eq(0).val('s');  // eq(0) for the first option element . eq(1) for the second option element ...
```

Comment: $('select[name=sec] option:first').eq(0).val('s');

I'm not sure I completely understood it, but does the line above change the first option value to 's'?

Comment: in your comment here $('select[name=sec] option:first').eq(0) its wrong .. please follow my answer .. choose $('select[name=sec] option:first').val()  or $('select[name=sec] option').eq(0).val()

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make selected an other option use this code:

```
$('select[name="sec"]').find('option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
$('select[name="sec"]').find('option[value="s"]').attr('selected','selected');
```

This script removes the default selection (the first option) and select the option which has "s" value. For the Demo:

```js
$('select[name="sec"]').find('option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
$('select[name="sec"]').find('option[value="s"]').attr('selected','selected');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="sec" style="margin-top:5px;width:138px;">
    <option value="topics">Forum Topics</option>
    <option value="s">Items for Sale</option>
    <option value="b">Want to Buys</option>
    <option value="users">Members</option>
</select>
```

You have to find this  element in the DOM. For this you should find the first parent container element of the  which has ID or CLASS attribute. From that element you can create a search for the element what you want by using the .find() method.
If there're more  element which has name attribute with "sec" value you should build a chain of find which separate that you want. For that you can use these function templates:

```
$(#CONTAINER_ID).find(.SUBCONTAINER_CLASS).find(ELEMENT_TYPE);
$(#CONTAINER_ID).find(SUBCONTAINER_TYPE).find(OTHER_SUBCONTAINER_TYPE:eq(X));
```